# How do I close the DOS screen after I run a pascal program and I'm stuck in a loop?

Tags: pascal, turbo-pascal

Lets say I've made a pascal program.  Let's say that I haven't saved the program and I mistakenly created a loop. I ran the program and I'm stuck in a loop in the DOS run screen. How do I get out without <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>? The program I am using is Turbo Pascal.

Comment: CTRL+C should stop program execution

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should do the trick, sometimes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If its stuck in a tight loop, you can't.  But if it is writing to the screen or checking the keyboard then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will do the trick.